# Who's the director?

Tags: higurashi-when-they-cry

I just watched *"Higurashi no Naku Koro Ni"*. I haven't seen any sequel yet.

In the first story arc, when Rena and Mion trap Keiichi in his own house, they speak of some sort of coming "*director*" (or perhaps *principal*, depending on the translation). Keiichi asks who's him, but they just insist with *"the director is the director!"*.

Who's the director?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The identity of the director is revealed within the first season, so if you haven't finished it, just keep watching. However, given your comment, it seems you have finished it so the explanation is below.

The "director" is one of the ways the children in the show refer to the head of the medical clinic, Irie Kyōsuke. Since he is the coach of the baseball team, he is often referred to as "Kantoku" which translates to "manager," "director," "coach," etc.

I've watched the show with several different sets of subtitles, and I've seen all of those translations at least once.

Comment: Oh, I see. And why were they expecting him to come?

Comment: Keiichi had just been hit over the head with a bat or something. Presumably, his friends found him unconscious in one form or another. Therefore, his friends called Irie, the head of the medical clinic, to attend to him.

Comment: Why are you spoiling it? I think you should answer with spoiler text cc @Omega